# Converting unicode character to a single hexadecimal value in C#

Tags: c#

I am getting a character from a emf record using Encoding.Unicode.GetString and the resulting string contains only one character but has two bytes. I don't have any idea about the encoding scheme and the multi byte character set. I want to convert that character to its equivalent single hexadecimal value.Can you help me regarding this..

Comment: What do you mean by "multibyte character"? A UTF-8 sequence, or just a code point?

Comment: And yet elsewhere you say you've got *2* bytes. Do you realise that not all Unicode characters - not even the whole of the BMP - can be represented in two bytes in UTF-8?

Answer (score 6):

It's not clear what you mean. A `char` in C# is a 16-bit unsigned value. If you've got a *binary* data source and you want to get Unicode characters, you should use an `Encoding` to decode the binary data into a string, that you can access as a sequence of `char` values.

You can convert a `char` to a hex string by first converting it to an integer, and then using the X format specifier like this:

```
char = '\u0123';
string hex = ((int)c).ToString("X4"); // Now hex = "0123"
```

Now, that leaves one more issue: *surrogate pairs*. Values which aren't in the *Basic Multilingual Plane* (U+0000 to U+FFFF) are represented by two UTF-16 code units - a high surrogate and a low surrogate. You can use the `char.IsSurrogate*`  methods to check for surrogate pairs... although it's harder (as far as I can see) to then convert a surrogate pair into a UCS-4 value. If you're lucky, you won't need to deal with this... if you're happy converting your binary data into a sequence of UTF-16 code units instead of strict UCS-4 values, you don't need to worry.

EDIT: Given your comments, it's still not entirely clear what you've got to start with. You say you've got two bytes... are they separate, or in a byte array? What do they represent? Text in a particular encoding, presumably... but which encoding? Once you know the encoding, you can convert a byte array into a string easily:

```
byte[] bytes = ...;
// For example, if your binary data is UTF-8
string text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
char firstChar = text[0];
string hex = ((int)firstChar).ToString("X4");
```

If you could edit your question to give more details about your actual situation, it would be a lot easier to help you get to a solution. If you're generally confused about encodings and the difference between text and binary data, you might want to read my [article about it](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/unicode.html).

Comment: Is there any known method to convert the surrogate pairs into a UCS-4 Value?

Comment: @Parthi27887: You can certainly do it manually - have a look at my Utf32String class in MiscUtil for example: http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/miscutil. I'm sure there's something in the framework to do this, but I can't find it. I'd expect it to be in String.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(theChar.ToString())
     .Aggregate("", (agg, val) => agg + val.ToString("X2"));
```

However, since you don't specify exactly what encoding that the character is in, this could fail. Futher, you don't make it very clear if you want the output to be a string of hex chars or bytes. I'm guessing the former, since I'd guess you want to generate HTML. Let me know if any of this is wrong.

Comment: That seems a pretty roundabout way of doing it to me, when you can just use `ToString` after converting it to an int...

Comment: Point taken. My perspective is skewed by performing this technique on binary streams. On the other hand, would the cast-to-int method work on code-points that need more than a `Char` to represent them?

Comment: Hi Kaizen

i couldn't compile it , it shows some error message that "System.Array does not contain a definition for Aggregate"

Comment: @Parthi27887 - you need to be using C# 3.0 and import the System.Linq namespace for this to work. Try John's solution, as it is more straightfoward.

Comment: I want the output as a string

Comment: What version of Visual Studio?

Comment: Ok, then just include the using System.Linq statement at the top of your code, and it should compile.

Comment: It still won't work if you're using VS2008 but targeting .NET 2.0 though. May not be a problem, but it's worth mentioning.

Comment: Ah, yes. Thanks, Jon. In case of using .Net v2.0, add a reference to System.Core assembly.

Comment: it worked now and all i need is the character contains 2 bytes and i want a single hexadecimal value(4byte not an 8byte value)

Comment: can you get me? It just concatenates the hexadecimal value of the bytes used to represent the character all i need is converting that multibyte value into a single byte and then converting it to hex..

Comment: @codekaizen: Adding a reference to a .NET 3.5 assembly from .NET 2.0 is a really bad idea IMO. If you want to use LINQ to Objects from .NET 2.0, LINQBridge is the better way forward.

Comment: @Parthi27887: No, you don't want to convert the multibyte value into a single *byte* - you want to convert it into a single *char*. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Get thee to StringInfo:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.stringinfo.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8k5611at.aspx

> The .NET Framework supports text elements. A text element is a unit of text that is displayed as a single character, called a grapheme. A text element can be a base character, a surrogate pair, or a combining character sequence. The StringInfo class provides methods that allow your application to split a string into its text elements and iterate through the text elements. For an example of using the StringInfo class, see String Indexing.

Answer (score 0):

I created an extension method to convert unicode or non-unicode string to hex string.

I shared for whom concern.

```
public static class StringHelper
    {
        public static string ToHexString(this string str)
        {
            byte[] bytes = str.IsUnicode() ? Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str) : Encoding.Default.GetBytes(str);

            return BitConverter.ToString(bytes).Replace("-", string.Empty);
        }

        public static bool IsUnicode(this string input)
        {
            const int maxAnsiCode = 255;

            return input.Any(c => c > maxAnsiCode);
        }
}
```