# Escape Accents To HtmlEntity as Hex

Tags: c#, html, unicode, hex, entity

This is my unicode String 
>

> Désastres

The above String need to be converted to HTML Entity (Hex) as

`D&#x00E9;sastres`

Below is the code, it converts the string to html entiry but in Decimal.

Can anyone help me to get the desired result?

```
static string EscapeAccentsToHtmlEntities(string source)
{
    int length = source.Length;
    var escaped = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        char ch = source[i];

        if ((ch >= '\x00a0') && (ch < 'Ā')) //U+{0:X4} 
        {
            escaped.AppendFormat("&#{0};", ((int)ch).ToString(NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)); //"&#{0};"
        }
        else
        {
            escaped.Append(ch);
        }
    }

    return escaped.ToString();
}
```

Explaination:
possible duplicates of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6639770/how-do-i-get-the-unicode-hex-representation-of-a-symbol-out-of-the-html-using-ja) is for javascript / jquery

Comment: @mplungjan  Except that it's a completely different programming language?

Comment: Ah, Missed the C# since it was tagged HTML - I never see C# questions. - Seems there are however a few answers here for C# too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170523/converting-unicode-character-to-a-single-hexadecimal-value-in-c-sharp

Comment: @mplungjan Yep, true. Still pretty duplicate, I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use the correct `ToString()` format for the integer:

```
escaped.AppendFormat("&#x{0};", ((int)ch).ToString("X4"));
```

Comment: but it converts to &amp;#x00E9; why?

Comment: Probably because you do an additional HTML escaping on the final string somehow? You need to put that in this function too, in the `else` case, and then leave the string alone. I can't tell you how/where that happens without more of your code though. If you use an xml writer of some kind, be sure to make it write that content as already being HTML to avoid that kind of stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Add reference to `System.Web` to your project and use this method:

```
using System.Web;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions, 

private string HtmlEntityHex(string strToReplace)
{
    string strReplaced = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(strToReplace);
    MatchCollection xMatches = Regex.Matches(strReplaced, @"&#(\d+);");
    foreach (Match xMatch in xMatches)
    {
        strReplaced = strReplaced.Replace(xMatch.Groups[0].Value.ToString(), "&#" + int.Parse(xMatch.Groups[1].Value).ToString("X").PadLeft(4, '0') + ";");
    }
    return strReplaced;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!